# ssh in for loop and excute command as su

Tags: debian

```
kamal@shell001:~ $ for i in `cat FILE`;do ssh $i -l localadmin 'su;ipmitool bmc reset cold';done
localadmin@server1's password: 
Unknown command: su;ipmitool
```

Can someone please suggest how to execute ssh and switch to `su` and run any command. Thanks you

I am using Debian 4.1.35-1 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org).

`sudo` doesn't work.

```
server1# su;ipmitool mc info 
Unknown command: su;ipmitool

server1# su|ipmitool mc info 
Unknown command: su|ipmitool 

server1# su 
root@server11:~#
```

Command after su with semicolon is not working. After switching as root, the command works.

Comment: 1) Please format your question and 2) did you try `whereis su`? and also `man su` as you are not using it properly, but at the same time it is difficult to understand what you want to do. Are you mixing `su` with `sudo` maybe?

Comment: Add relevant information into the text of your question that you can edit, not as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell operators only work in a shell.

```
ssh ... sh -c '...;...'
```

Comment: for i in `cat FILE`;do ssh localadmin@$i "su -c 'ipmitool bmc reset cold'";done

Thank you it's working.